# How to update HFSS component/block elements throughout design?

Tags: rf, simulation, cad

I'm trying to create a model in HFSS that has a particular block (in this case an SMP connector footprint) that is repeated a number of times throughout the design. It involves geometry I've drawn for the footprint and also a 3D Component from a vendor. I want to be able to connect these with coplanar waveguide (which has involves drawing via walls along a path). I need to be able to parameterize and adjust these things in the model.

- How can I best do this in a reusable way (3d component?) that can then be updated later in one place and be automatically (or with a single click) reflected everywhere I'm using the component?
- How do I deal with material intersections in bulk, both with this component and with arrays of things like vias?
- These things are all easy to accomplish using something like kicad, but that's not suitable for running EM simulations.

A common source of issues for me is dealing with vias and groundplane shapes. These both often need to be unioned with and/or subtracted from other things. That's fine for a few items, but once I'm dealing with arrays or grids of these things, it becomes impractical to deal with them one by one.

I've looked at:

- the 3D Layout Design program, but so far I haven't seen any major advantage to using it. (For example, there seems to be no tool for just drawing via walls along a path, much less coplanar or other waveguide without doing the whole thing manually. Perhaps it can solve my reusable footprint issue though?)
- 3D Components, but they seem to run into a lot of issues with material intersections.
- Tutorials from Ansys and elsewhere on the internet. They all are relatively elementary. I can model things, but how do I scale that to more complex designs?

Comment: To your first question - I’ve had similar issues with HFSS. It tends to just be a very manual tool. I’ve had a bit of luck creating structures using Python code/scripts. They are a pain in too, with poor debugging capability and documentation lacking. But once I hit the bullet and got it working, it was nice.

Comment: Thanks; yeah that's what I do in general right now to get around this problem. It's just so cumbersome and I keep thinking I must be just missing something big---how can the whole industry just live with this??